# Locale Sensitive dateFormat String

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

Is there a date formate string for NSDateFormatter that will detect 12 or 24 and 1 or 0 based hour formats?

Unless I'm reading it wrong, the Unicode spec says that one can use the 'j' to this end. For example, the following should use 1-12, 0-23, or 1-24 hours depending on the locale, but NSDateFormatter just creates an empty string.

```
NSDateFormatter *minuteFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
minuteFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
minuteFormatter.dateFormat = @"jj";
```

I've seen many suggesting to use the following to properly interpret the user's locale, but I only want a string with the hour in it, and would rather not have to parse the resulting string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

Comment: Actually, in most cases the date formatter switches automatically, overriding the format string.  The latest Unicode spec is indecipherable.

Comment: I have the option of hh or HH and some other options. hh prints 1-12, HH prints 0 - 24, both regardless of locale. Are you saying that NSDateFormatter overrides those settings?

Comment: In some circumstances, yes, iOS ignores the format.

Comment: I dug back through it a bit.  It's only in the case that the 12/24 switch in Settings has been mucked with that iOS overrides (ignores) the format.  But, reading the spec, I can't make heads or tails of what "j" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 4):

from the [date format specs](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

> This is a special-purpose symbol. It must not occur in pattern or skeleton data. Instead, it is reserved for use in skeletons passed to APIs doing flexible date pattern generation. In such a context, it requests the preferred hour format for the locale (h, H, K, or k), as determined by whether h, H, K, or k is used in the standard short time format for the locale. In the implementation of such an API, 'j' must be replaced by h, H, K, or k before beginning a match against availableFormats data. Note that use of 'j' in a skeleton passed to an API is the only way to have a skeleton request a locale's preferred time cycle type (12-hour or 24-hour).

Which probably means it needs to be resolved before it gets to the date formatting.

Try using `+ (NSString *)dateFormatFromTemplate:(NSString *)template options:(NSUInteger)opts locale:(NSLocale *)locale` to retrieve a format string.

```
NSString *format = [NSDate dateFormatFromTemplate:@"jj" options:0 locale: myLocale];
hourFormatter.dateFormat = format;
```

Comment: I guess you meant `jj` in the template string.